# My Ubuntu has crashed! How to solve

Tags: 20.04, updates

I am very happy with my installation. The Software Updater told me there were some some updates to install. I accepted. I waited but it stopped responding, so I did a force quit. Afterwards I couldn't open files and some apps. I tried to restart. Ubuntu shows this screen.

[image: Error ubuntu]

I tried to reboot and turned the power off and on, but nothing worked.
Ubuntu version: 22.04
Estimated installation cleared with errors = ~1 hours

Comment: Many critical details are missing from your question. What version of Ubuntu are you using? To be clear you did not wait for it to finish the update and did a reboot with the power switch? How long did you wait?

Comment: I am using 20.04. and yes, i wait maybe ~1 hours. The updates dint cleared but i need to work with my laptop. So i force quit

Comment: Please edit the question and add the info there. Comments for people trying to help you not for more or missing info for the question. Thanks.